# Protected Google Sheets With Loop

Tags: javascript

This function checks whether a certain range of cells in the same row as the dates in the "A" column are more than 2 days previous, then locks those cells. This is good, but I want to make sure there aren't duplicate protected ranges in google sheets.

I have another script that just deletes all protected ranges, but that ends up bogging down the script as it has to check every cell every time to see if it matches the date.

I would MUCH rather it ignore any already protected cells.

Any suggestions for an "if" statement that would skip already locked cells?

Also, is it necessary for the second if statement below to first check "protection.canDomainEdit()" before just setting it to "protection.setDomainEdit(false)"?

```
for (var i = 310; i <= 368; i++) 
//I began "i" at this number because I don't need to attend to the entire sheet.
{
  var datecell = "A" + i;  
  var date = sheet.getRange(datecell).getValue();

  if (date <= twoDaysAgo && date >= thirtyDaysAgo)
  {

    var Lock_Range = ("F" + i + ":H" + i),
        protection = sheet.getRange(Lock_Range).protect(),
        description = "Locked " + i;   

    protection.setDescription(description);

       protection.addEditor(me);
       protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());

       if (protection.canDomainEdit()) 
       {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
       }

  }
}
```